# Besides files, what informations about a website are also being cahed into a browser?

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, cache, godaddy

My website was pointing to a shared hosting server in Godaddy, it is managed by cPanel. Recently I bought a Godaddy managed VPS. After I had WHM/cPanel installed on it I moved my website to this VPS. What I did was:
1) create a new cPanel account associated with a temporary subdomain(temp.mystie.com) in the new VPS
2) After I transfer files and databases over from the old hosting, I test it and make sure temp.mysite.com is good for visit.
3) I then change the A record of mystie.com to the IP of the new VPS.
4) Then I add mysite.com as an alias of temp.mysite.com in the new cPanel (yes I am lazy)
5) Then I go to the old cPanel and remove mysite.com from it (it was listed as an addon domain)

Now after all this, some of my clients complain that when they try to open the site, they got an error saying the IP of mysite.com can't be found while I myself have no problem opening up the website. I believe if they open it in incognito mode there should be no problem. Please be noted this happened 24 hours after I changed the DNS and I can't tell all of my clients to use incognito mode.

So I'm wondering if I can do anything to prevent this from happening, and I need to learn more about this cache thing. Apparently not only files like `.js` `.css` `.jpg` are cached, but also some other information is also being cached, like DNS information and, seemingly to me in other cases, PHP execution mode. So what kinds of information are being cached exactly? And on my end, can I do anything to prevent my client to get an error when they try to open my website as usual after I recently did some major change to my website?

Comment: Hi, the IP not found point to a DNS issue, please ask a customer to do a DNS lookup to send you the result.

Answer (score 0):

DNS is cached by local ISP's a lot of the time, which is definitely the issue you seem to be having with some of your clients. It could be anywhere from 24 hours to 48+

One solution is to put [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com) in-front of your IP - Basically it will act as a proxy, so your domain will point to Cloudflares IP (Which never changes) and in the backend, you can update the IP as much as you want, and it will be almost instant. CloudFlare does have a free plan, and also provides a host of other features such as DDoS protection, CDN etc. All without any setup from your end. I'd highly recommend it in general!